# Why does the page refresh on the same localhost:3000 instead of going to localhost:3000/zipcode etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-5, ruby-on-rails-7

When I press Enter or hit the "Search" button, it stays on the localhost:3000 page and doesn't change to the /zipcode.

Whenever I hit Enter my terminal says:

```
Started POST "/zipcode" for ::1 at 2023-04-20 19:26:35 -0400
Processing by HomeController#zipcode as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "zipcode"=>"123123", "commit"=>"Search"}
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering home/zipcode.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered home/zipcode.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 10)
  Rendered home/_navbar.html.erb (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 290)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 18.9ms | Allocations: 7172)
Completed 200 OK in 178ms (Views: 19.2ms | Allocations: 8388)
```

Here is my project:

Home_controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    require 'net/http'
    require 'json'

    @url = 'https://www.airnowapi.org/aq/observation/zipCode/current/?   format=application/json&zipCode=23662&distance=25&API_KEY=B4B8AEE7-95A3-413F-B122-9F3DDCE35C85'
    @uri = URI(@url)
    @response = Net::HTTP.get(@uri)
    @output = JSON.parse(@response)

    # Check for empty return results
    if @output.empty?
        @final_output = "Error"
    elsif !@output
        @final_output = "Error"
    else
        @final_output = @output[0]['AQI']
    end

    if @final_output == "Error"
        @api_color = "gray"
    elsif @final_output <= 50
        @api_color = "green"
        @api_description = "Good (0-50) Air quality is considered satisfactory, and air pollutioon poses little or no risk."
    elsif @final_output >= 51 && @final_output <= 100
        @api_color = "yellow"
        @api_description = "Moderate (51-100) Air quality is acceptable; however, for some pollutants there may be a moderate health concern for a very small number of people who are unusually sensitive to air pollution."
    elsif @final_output >= 101 && @final_output <= 150
        @api_color = "orange"
        @api_description = "Unhealthy for Sensitive Groups (101-150) Although general public is not likely to be affected at this AQI range, people with lung disease, older adults and children are at a greater risk from exposure to ozone, whereas persons with heart and lunch disease, older adults and children are at greater risk from the presence of particles in the air."
    elsif @final_output >= 151 && @final_output <= 200
        @api_color = "red"
        @api_description = "Unhealthy (151-200) Everyone may begin to experience health effects; members of sensitive groups may experience more serious health effects."
    elsif @final_output >= 201 && @final_output <= 300
        @api_color = "purple"
        @api_description = "Very Unhealthy (201-300) Health alert: everyone may experience more serious health effects."
    elsif @final_output >= 301 && @final_output <= 500
        @api_color = "maroon"
        @api_description = "Hazardous (301-500) Health warnings of warnings of emergency conditions. The entire population is more likely to be affected."

    end
  end

  def zipcode
    @zipquery = params[:zipcode]
    if params[:zipcode] == ""
      @zip_query = "Hey you forgot to enter a zipcode!"
    elsif params[:zipcode]

    end
  end

  def zipcode
    @zip_query = params[:zipcode]
    if params[:zipcode] == ""
      @zip_query = "Hey you fogot to enter a zipcode!" 
    elsif params[:zipcode]


      @url = 'https://www.airnowapi.org/aq/observation/zipCode/current/?format=application/json&zipCode=' + @zip_query + 'distance=25&API_KEY=B4B8AEE7-95A3-413F-B122-9F3DDCE35C85'
      @uri = URI(@url)
      @response = Net::HTTP.get(@uri)
      @output = JSON.parse(@response)

      # Check for empty return results
      if @output.empty?
          @final_output = "Error"
      elsif !@output
          @final_output = "Error"
      else
          @final_output = @output[0]['AQI']
      end

      if @final_output == "Error"
          @api_color = "gray"
      elsif @final_output <= 50
          @api_color = "green"
          @api_description = "Good (0-50) Air quality is considered satisfactory, and air pollution poses little or no risk."
      elsif @final_output >= 51 && @final_output <= 100
          @api_color = "yellow"
          @api_description = "Moderate (51-100) Air quality is acceptable; however, for some pollutants there may be a moderate health concern for a very small number of people who are unusually sensitive to air pollution."
      elsif @final_output >= 101 && @final_output <= 150
          @api_color = "orange"
          @api_description = "Unhealthy for Sensitive Groups (101-150) Although general public is not likely to be affected at this AQI range, people with lung disease, older adults and children are at a greater risk from exposure to ozone, whereas persons with heart and lunch disease, older adults and children are at greater risk from the presence of particles in the air."
      elsif @final_output >= 151 && @final_output <= 200
          @api_color = "red"
          @api_description = "Unhealthy (151-200) Everyone may begin to experience health effects; members of sensitive groups may experience more serious health effects."
      elsif @final_output >= 201 && @final_output <= 300
          @api_color = "purple"
          @api_description = "Very Unhealthy (201-300) Health alert: everyone may experience more serious health effects."
      elsif @final_output >= 301 && @final_output <= 500
          @api_color = "maroon"
          @api_description = "Hazardous (301-500) Health warnings of warnings of emergency conditions. The entire population is more likely to be affected."


    end

    end
  end



end
```

nav_bar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary navbar bg-dark" data-bs-theme="dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Ozone</a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    
    

    </ul>
    <%= form_tag zipcode_path, :method => 'POST' do %>
    <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <%= text_field_tag 'zipcode', nil, placeholder: "Search Zipcode", class: "form-control mr-sm-2" %> 
      <%= submit_tag 'Search', class: 'btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0' %>

      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>

</nav>
```

application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Weather</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= render 'home/navbar' %>
    <div class="container">
      <br/>
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

zipcode.html.erb:

```
<div class="jumbotron <%= @api_color %>">
  <h1 class="display-4"><%= @final_output %></h1>
  <p class="lead">This is the current ozone air quality readout for the <%= @zip_query %> zipcode.</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <p><%= @api_description %></p>
  <br/>
  <p class="lead">

</div>
```

Routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'home/zipcode'
  root 'home#index'

  post "zipcode" => 'home#zipcode'
     end
```

I tried switching the roots and working between `<form>` and `<div>` but whenever I refresh nothing on the page seems to change. It updates the link I sent in the home controller, it doesn't lookup the zipcode typed in and place the information.

Answer (score 0):

You have two methods in the controller with the same name. Try renaming either the `POST` or `GET` endpoint in the routes and in the controller and that should take care of it.

Comment: what are the two methods you are referring to? A lot of them repeat.